# Obj.-C: method to make a command line tool speak text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've been having fun using the "say" command in Terminal, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a command line tool that I write "speak" its output at runtime. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't see how all this is related to Xcode. What if you make this tool using GCC/Clang's CLI interface and a simple text editor only, not even touching Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `NSSpeechSynthesizer` for code you write yourself.

And, of course, the [Speech Synthesis Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/SpeechOverview/SpeechOverview.html) is pertinent reading too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to execute terminal commands from Cocoa.